# In 1600s, in 500s

Tags: word-choice

Is "in the five hundreds" for 500s and "in the sixteen hundreds" for 1600 the only correct pronunciation,or is "in one thousand six hundreds" also correct?

1. The Persians were eating round flat bread with cheese in the 500s.
2. Many people think the English found out about curry from people in India in the  1600s.

Comment: Since we _almost_ always say dates as "sixteen twenty" and so on, it's "the sixteen hundreds". Personally, I prefer "the seventeenth century", because to me "the 1600s" means the decade 1600-1609, but many people do use it to refer to the century.

Comment: Nobody says "in the one thousand six hundreds", because "in the sixteen hundreds" is not only clearer but shorter.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, is it according to this explanation that native speakers wouldn't use "in the five hundreds" for  "in the 500s" but say "in the six century" instead because 500s is before 1100? The explanation:   "Before 1100, things like in the 1000s or in the 800s are far less common, and so writers will most likely choose only "in the eleventh century"/"in the 11th century" or "in the ninth century"/"in the 9th century".

Comment: If you mean that dates in the first millennium are less commonly talked about by non-historians - yes, I think that's right.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, So in 1300 would be either "in the thirteen hundreds" or "in the fourteenth century"  but in 400s would be "in the fifth century" rather than "in the four hundreds"? Right?

Comment: I don't remember ever hearing anyone refer to 'the 500s' etc., but that's not to say that no-one ever has done. I'm sure a historian would say 'the sixth century'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, so it's not wrong, it is just not as often used. I mean 500s=  "in the five hundreds" instead of more common  "in the six century" and 400s= "in the four hundreds" instead of more common  "in the fifth century". Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I said that _I didn't remember hearing it_ but [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+500s&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20500s%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20500s%3B%2Cc0) shows that it has in fact become much more common in recent decades, with reference to centuries BC as well as AD/CE. (NB it's 'the six**th** century'.)

Comment: @Kate Bunting,  one more question, if you please.  In 1300s would be either "in the thirteen hundreds" or "in the fourteenth century". Right?

Comment: Yes - I said in my first comment that 'the 1600s' is the seventeenth century. The first century was the years _before_ AD 100.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "in the sixteen-hundreds" is quite clear, one would rarely talk about "in the 500s" and never about "the one thousand six hundreds"

Instead you can say "in the seventeenth century" or "in the sixth century"  (and you might add "sixth century AD" as, to be honest, I wouldn't have been surprised if Persians were eating bread and cheese from the sixth century BC)

Just remember that the 16 hundreds is the 17th century (etc) Its always out by one.

Comment: Except if you use the words correctly, then the 16 hundreds are the years starting with 16, that is 1600 to 1699, while the first year was one, so the 17th century is 1601 to 1700. (Now obviously you will have to fight clueless politicians like one who claimed 2,000 was Jesus' 2000th birthday, and those who closed down the Millenium Dome in London just at the end of the previous Millennium).